# Stop UITableView from animating for keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uitextview

I have an `UITableView` with a single cell that contains an `UITextView`. When calling `-becomeFirstResponder` on the `UITextView` my `UITableView` gets messed up by the automatic animation. This **only** occurs when the `UITextView` has to scroll down for the end of the text.
I already tried disabling scrolling on the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the needs of your interface, you could probably do what you're asking by making the parent view controller an instance of `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` (which is what provides that "slide to get out of the way of the keyboard" behavior).

Indeed, if your UI consists solely of a text view, you probably don't need a table view at all.